# What is the most effective policy for reducing rapes on college campus?

Tags: education

Senator Gillibrand is sponsoring legislation to try to reduce the [rape epidemic](http://www.democratandchronicle.com/story/news/local/2014/05/25/gillibrand-makes-campus-sexual-assaults-next-cause/9579573/) on college campuses.

Right now **there are no incentives for colleges to report these crimes** or to make sure that justice is done,'' the New York Democrat said in an interview. "Their incentive today is to make sure they are not known as a **rape school**. And the financial penalty is so low that they don't report the cases to the Department of Education.

Gillibrand notes that currently the [risk of sexual assault](http://www.buzzfeed.com/katenocera/senators-kirsten-gillibrand-and-claire-mccaskill-begin-to-ta) at a college is quite high.

“[T]he price of a college education should not include a **1 in 5 chance of being sexually assaulted.** America’s colleges and universities are the best in the world,” Gillibrand said in a statement. “But it is simply unacceptable that they become havens for rape and sexual assault. It is time to take this crisis head on and end the scourge of sexual assault on our college campuses, hold offenders accountable, and keep our students safe.”

Besides stop sending women to these rape schools, [which hasn't been effective](http://www.aei.org/publication/stunning-college-degree-gap-women-have-earned-almost-10-million-more-college-degrees-than-men-since-1982/), **What is the most effective way of preventing sexual assaults on college campuses?** (Studies that have shown reduced risk before and after policy changes/behavior changes/etc. are required)

Comment: Instances of rape have been declining steadily since at least the early 1970s, this is despite more awareness of the the crime and more victim-centric attitudes. So there is hardly a rape epidemic. Unless of course you take unproven and unsubstantiated claims or accusations of rape at face value.

Comment: I'm not closing unilaterally but I don't like the inherent opinion based nature of this question. This is a "truth" question, but I'd prefer not to stick my neck out until I have others who agree.

Comment: @AffableGeek, "truth" question? Studies cannot show reduced risk for certain behaviors (or previous policy changes)? How do we know that drinking increases your risk whilst driving?

Comment: You're asking "what is the most effective" policy. That implies a list then a comparison etc.

Comment: @AffableGeek, but how does a list then comparison imply that this is a "truth" question and inherently opinion based?

Comment: Some brands of makeups are very effective man-repellents. A mouthful of chemical can upset a man's appetite for that particular woman for many years.